# If condition is failing in the GitLab CI

Tags: linux, gitlab, gitlab-ci

following is my Gitlab CI code:-

```
stages:
  - check

variables:
  JIRA_HEADER: "Accept: application/json"

jira:
  stage: check
  before_script:
    #- apk add jq curl
    - apk add --no-cache bash jq curl
    
  image: python:3.7.4-alpine3.9
  script:
    - export MERGE_REQUEST_JIRA_ID=$(echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE} | sed -r "s/^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+-[0-9]+).*/\1/")
    - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE
    
    - export JIRA_DETAIL=$(curl -u ${JIRA_USERNAME}:${JIRA_PASSWORD} -H "${JIRA_HEADER}" -X GET https://${JIRA_SERVER}/rest/api/2/issue/${MERGE_REQUEST_JIRA_ID}?fields=status)
    - echo $JIRA_DETAIL

    # extract the JIRA key id, this also validates JIRA issue referenced is valid
    - export JIRA_KEY_ID=$(echo ${JIRA_DETAIL} | jq -e '.key')
    - echo $JIRA_KEY_ID

    # extract the JIRA status
    - export JIRA_STATUS=$(echo ${JIRA_DETAIL} | jq '.fields.status.name')
    - echo $JIRA_STATUS
    - |
       if [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" == "^(Done|Completed|Closed)$" ]] 
        then 
          echo "Invalid JIRA (Done/Completed/Closed) found!"
          exit 1
        else echo "Valid JIRA Id found!" 
       fi    
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

I'm trying to validate the JIRA status by calling its API after retrieving Jira id from title of Merge Request. There is a problem in the `If` condition below `if [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" == "^(Done|Completed|Closed)$" ]]` as it is not validating it properly. Every time, the else condition is getting executed and printing the message as **Valid JIRA Id found!**
I would really appreciate if someone can help me to fix this minor issue. I want to gracefully exit the job with this message in the `if` block as **Invalid JIRA (Done/Completed/Closed) found!** whenever the Jira status found to be in any of the given values as **Done, Completed or Closed.**

Comment: What does the `echo $JIRA_STATUS` print?

Comment: It prints the status like Done, Open, etc

Comment: I'm finally able to resolve this issue by modifying the code like below:-

    - |
          if test -z "$(echo ${JIRA_STATUS} | sed -r "s/\"(Done|Completed|Closed)\"//")" 
            then 
              echo "Not a valid Jira (Done/Completed/Closed)"; exit 1
            else 
              echo "Valid Jira found!"; echo $?
          fi

I had used the test command along with if-else condition in Linux to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm finally able to resolve this issue by modifying the code like below:-

```
- |
      if test -z "$(echo ${JIRA_STATUS} | sed -r "s/\"(Done|Completed|Closed)\"//")" 
        then 
          echo "Not a valid Jira (Done/Completed/Closed)"; exit 1
        else 
          echo "Valid Jira found!"; echo $?
      fi
```

I had used the test command along with if-else condition in Linux to make it work